# How to plot in xz-plane?

Tags: plotting, interpolation

Using the following code I am able to plot x(t) and z(t) values with respect to time. But how to do a plot with x(t) values as x-axis and z(t) values as y-axis. Any suggestions please.

```
sol = NDSolve[{Derivative[1][x][t] == -x[t] + y[t], 
   Derivative[1][y][t] == -x[t] - 0.01 y[t] - y[t] z[t], 
   Derivative[1][z][t] == -0.5 z[t] + x[t]^2 - 77, x[0] == 0.1, 
   y[0] == 0.1, z[0] == 0.1}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 200}, 
  MaxSteps -> 1000000]

Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], z[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 200}, Frame -> True, 
 Axes -> None]
T1 = Table[{x[i], z[i]} /. sol, {i, 0, 200, 0.01}]
```

Thank you

Comment: Try `ParametricPlot`

Comment: 3D also work. `sol = NDSolve[{Derivative[1][x][t] == -x[t] + y[t], 
    Derivative[1][y][t] == -x[t] - 0.01 y[t] - y[t] z[t], 
    Derivative[1][z][t] == -0.5 z[t] + x[t]^2 - 77, x[0] == 0.1, 
    y[0] == 1, z[0] == 0.1}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 200}];
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 200}, 
 Axes -> None, BoxRatios -> 1]`

Answer (score 4):

Try `ParametricPlot`

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], z[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 200},Frame -> True, Axes -> None, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: yes its working.

Comment: In Parametricplot is there any option to set PlotRange for the axes?

Comment: Same options as in `Plot&Co`

Comment: In the system when 77 is replaced by 200 or higher values,  x(t) values are around (-100,100) whereas z(t) values are around (-1000, 5000) so in such cases how to apply LogPlot in ParametricPlot?

Comment: @vicky Try the option `ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Log"}` inside `ParametricPlot`. It is displayed "red" but it works.